# pgfplots, tikz, node, pin: Change Anchor

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I annotate special points in my diagram and use a `node`/`pin` approach:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
        ]
    \addplot [domain=0:10]{x};
    \node[coordinate, pin={[align=left,pin distance = 10mm]-30:{Test Text Test\\ Text Test}}]
               at (axis cs:4,4) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to change the anchor for the pin line / pin egde -- here are two possibilities:

[image]

> **Is that possible?**

Comment: @gonzalo-medina Are you sure this is a duplicate to the question you referred to?

Comment: Yes; I'm completely sure. I myself tested the proposed code in the answer using your example code and allows you to do what you want.

Comment: I see it now - took me a minute :). Seems complicated. Thank you very much. When I searched the forum I did not find it. So basically there's no "out of the box" way.

Comment: No, no "out of the box" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative for `pin` is to place the text node directly, at the position you want. The the line can be drawn between the point on the curve and the node. Variant 1 connects to the west of the text node and variant 2 to the north.

Example:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
        ]
    \addplot [domain=0:10]{x};
    \draw
      (axis cs:3, 3) coordinate (tmp) % start point
      ++(-30:5mm)
      node[
        below right,
        align=left,
      ] (test) {Test Text Test\\Text Test}
      (test.west) -- (tmp)
    ;
    \draw
      (axis cs:6, 6) coordinate (tmp) % start point
      ++(-30:5mm)
      node[
        below right,
        align=left,
      ] (test) {Test Text Test\\Text Test}
      (test.north) -- (tmp)
    ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot Heiko. I would prefer a node/pin solution since it is less code and I like the elegance. But if there isn't a way then I do not have another choice.